# Looping String difficulty python 3

Tags: python, string, loops

The function of this code is to capitalize letter that appears in the even indexed and lowercase the letter that appears in the odd indexed. Moreover, if whitespace appears between the words, the index has to be reset to 0. As you can see, the first and the second words are executed correctly. Whereas, the third word is incorrect. Instead of C and S being capitalized, 0 and 2 index respectively, A and E are capitalized.

```
string = 'Weird string case'
result = ''
i=0
for m in string:
    if(i%2==0):
       result = result+m.upper()
       i+=1
    elif(m==' '):
       result = result + m
       i=0
    else:
       result = result + m.lower()
       i+=1
    print(result)
```

**Current Output**

```
 WeIrD StRiNg cAsE
```

**Expected Output**

```
 WeIrD StRiNg CaSe
```

Answer (score 1):

You should test if `m` is a space first; otherwise if the space occurs when `i` is even then `i` would not be reset:

```
string = 'Weird string case'
result = ''
i=0
for m in string:
    if(m==' '):
       result = result + m
       i=0
    elif(i%2==0):
       result = result+m.upper()
       i+=1
    else:
       result = result + m.lower()
       i+=1
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

little swaps can solve the problem:

```
string = 'Weird string case'
result = ''
i=0
for m in string:
    if(i%2!=0):
       result = result+m.lower()
       i+=1
    elif(m==' '):
       result = result + m
       i=0
    else:
       result = result + m.upper()
       i+=1
    print(result)
```

Or have a two-liner, (could be one very long tho), a list comprehension and a `map` and two `join`s:

```
s=''.join([i.lower() if idx%2 else i.upper() for idx,i in enumerate(string)]).split()
print(' '.join(map(lambda x: x.swapcase() if x[0].islower() else x,s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have fixed it.

```
string = 'Weird string case'
result = ''
i=0
for m in string:
    if(i%2==0):
       result = result+m.upper()
       i+=1
    elif(m==' '):
       result = result + m
       i=1
    else:
       result = result + m.lower()
       i+=1
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not explicitly asked for, but we could tokenize the string first. This makes it case the individual words:

```
import re
string = 'Weird string case'
result = ''
for word in re.split("\\s+", string):
    for index, char in enumerate(word, 1):
        result = result+char.lower() if index%2==0 else result + char.upper()
    result += " "
print(result)
```

A regular string.split(" ") works as well. I've just used regex for demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If we *enumerate* `string` we can trim down our `if, elif, else` statement to just an `if, else` that would be `not i % 2` for our `upper.()` and `else` for lower. We can append them to a list and then use `''.join(res)` to print the final product. Also `map` is an option and *list comprehension*

*map*

```
s = 'Weird string case'
res = list(map(lambda x: x.upper() if not s.index(x) % 2 else x.lower(), s))
print(''.join(res))
```

*list comprehension*

```
res = [v.upper() if not i % 2 else v.lower() for i, v in enumerate(s)]
print(''.join(res))
```

Full loop:

```
res = []

for i, v in enumerate(s):
    if not i % 2:
        res.append(v.upper())
    else:
        res.append(v.lower())

print(''.join(res))
```

> ```
> WeIrD StRiNg cAsE
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use another list

```
    string = 'Weird string case'
    words = string.split(" ") #This creates a list of substrings from your original string
    result = ''
    for word in words:
        for m in string:
            if(i%2==0):
               result = result+m.upper()
               i+=1
            elif(m==' '):
               result = result + m
               i=0
            else:
               result = result + m.lower()
               i+=1
           `enter code here` print(result)
```